# Deploy flask application without AWS access key

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-zappa

I have Python Flask application (due to ORM and psycopg2 stuff) using Zappa to deploy to lambda. I am using boto library to perform some S3 related, and I use this to initialize it:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY
)
```

But I want to avoid using `aws_access_key` and `aws_secret_access_key` in code.
I created a separate empty lambda function and set proper role and permission, then in function code, I skipped putting access and secret key

```
client = boto3.client('s3')
```

and this works fine. But when I use zappa to deploy my Flask application, even though I set the same role  and permission as above (and also give access to S3), it does not work.
Is there a way I can bypass putting `aws_access_key` and `aws_secret_access_key` in Flask app and get to deploy to lambda?

Comment: Use environment variables https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html

Answer (score 1):

Zappa recommends setting up [an AWS credentials file](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3D6U6WSFGOK2H/A-New-and-Standardized-Way-to-Manage-Credentials-in-the-AWS-SDKs).  This should allow you to keep the credentials out of your code but allow the SDK to find and use your credentials.